# UWP C# Menuflyout Unable To Display Item Properly During 1st Click

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-iot-core-10

I am having an issue with my code to add button from `json` where the first attempt i click `add button`, the `menuflyout` won't have any respond but second click attempt then it will work properly. 
Can advise did i do anything wrong? Thanks.

```
private async void AddButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    List<ClientList> clientLists;
    var jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<ClientList>));


    var myStream = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForReadAsync(CLIENTSLIST);

    clientLists = (List<ClientList>)jsonSerializer.ReadObject(myStream);
    var menuFlyout = new MenuFlyout();

    int isEmpty = myGrid.Children.Count;
    if (isEmpty == 0)
    {
        foreach (var device in clientLists)
        {
            var menuFlyoutItem = new MenuFlyoutItem() { Name = device.clientname, Text = device.clientname };
            menuFlyoutItem.Tag = device.clientaddress;
            menuFlyoutItem.Click += AddMenuFlyoutItem_Click;
            menuFlyout.Items.Add(menuFlyoutItem);
        }
    }else
    {
        foreach (var device in clientLists)
        {
            bool toAddButton = true;
            foreach (Button btn in myGrid.Children.OfType<Button>())
            {
                if (btn.Content.ToString() == device.clientname)
                {
                    toAddButton = false;
                }
            }
            if (toAddButton)
            {
                var menuFlyoutItem = new MenuFlyoutItem() { Name = device.clientname, Text = device.clientname };
                menuFlyoutItem.Tag = device.clientaddress;
                menuFlyoutItem.Click += AddMenuFlyoutItem_Click;
                menuFlyout.Items.Add(menuFlyoutItem);
            }
        }
    }
    AddButton.Flyout = menuFlyout;
}
```

Comment: Can you add some comment to your code? it is unclear what the if/else statement is checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are loading the data asynchronously here:

```
var myStream = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForReadAsync(CLIENTSLIST);
```

When this happens, UI continues executing the `Click` event, so the button is clicked (and `Flyout` is `null` the first time) and `Flyout` will never display. You should rather load the `Flyout` before that - either when the page loads or when the data source changes, so that when the user clicks, the flyout is already there. Doing loading in `Click` is simply too late, if you need an asynchronous operation to finish.

Alternatively you could set the flyout right at the start:

```
private async void AddButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var menuFlyout = new MenuFlyout();
    AddButton.Flyout = menuFlyout;
    List<ClientList> clientLists;
    var jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<ClientList>));


    var myStream = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForReadAsync(CLIENTSLIST);

    clientLists = (List<ClientList>)jsonSerializer.ReadObject(myStream);

    int isEmpty = myGrid.Children.Count;
    if (isEmpty == 0)
    {
        foreach (var device in clientLists)
        {
            var menuFlyoutItem = new MenuFlyoutItem() { Name = device.clientname, Text = device.clientname };
            menuFlyoutItem.Tag = device.clientaddress;
            menuFlyoutItem.Click += AddMenuFlyoutItem_Click;
            menuFlyout.Items.Add(menuFlyoutItem);
        }
    }else
    {
        foreach (var device in clientLists)
        {
            bool toAddButton = true;
            foreach (Button btn in myGrid.Children.OfType<Button>())
            {
                if (btn.Content.ToString() == device.clientname)
                {
                    toAddButton = false;
                }
            }
            if (toAddButton)
            {
                var menuFlyoutItem = new MenuFlyoutItem() { Name = device.clientname, Text = device.clientname };
                menuFlyoutItem.Tag = device.clientaddress;
                menuFlyoutItem.Click += AddMenuFlyoutItem_Click;
                menuFlyout.Items.Add(menuFlyoutItem);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This way, the flyout will appear, but will be empty until the asynchronous loading finishes and the items are actually added. Here you are just reading a file, so it should be barely noticeable. Although not as clean as pre-loading the flyout, it should get the job done too.

Comment: Hi @MartinZikmund Thanks. Because the content of my `menuflyout` changes as `clientlist` changes. Is there any suggestion where I could place the async operation in my current context? or the only way is to do it is like you mentioned when `clientlist` changes?

Comment: Try the second suggestion - e.g. moving AddButton.Flyout = menuFlyout; to the top

Comment: Hi @MartinZikmund .. second suggestion doesn't seem to work.. I move these lines to `page_loaded` and it works. 
`var jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<ClientList>));
            var myStream = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForReadAsync(CLIENTSLIST);
            clientLists = (List<ClientList>)jsonSerializer.ReadObject(myStream);`